# Column names not found in DataFrame - can't delete them - "... not found in axis"

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have DF that looks like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
0   row-a49t-ihm3.rpap  00000000-0000-0000-05D6-978893D301BF    0   1604696511  None    1604696511  None    { } 2002    JAN 31106   49927   755015820   386481929
1   row-njtn_crc8_qawh  00000000-0000-0000-3211-E4A718B8A756    0   1604696511  None    1604696511  None    { } 2002    FEB 27520   50982   664454223   361353242
2   row-tn8d-5xax-gcqz  00000000-0000-0000-9FC0-AB50DEE551EE    0   1604696511  None    1604696511  None    { } 2002    MAR 34225   58794   805666244   419385387
3   row-bjnm-jnr7.7rbw  00000000-0000-0000-FE23-E2E416AC13DB    0   1604696511  None    1604696511  None    { } 2002    APR 36452   59817   846368297   433061150
```

`0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13` are column names according to:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
```

Loop prints this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

However i can't delete them using this:

```
df.drop(columns=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7'], inplace=True)
```

If it changes anything DataFrame was imported from Json file. What is causing the issue - column names are correct?

Comment: Your list of column names in `drop` are strings. They are probably ints. Do `df.drop(columns=df.columns[:8])`

Comment: df.drop(0, axis=1, inplace=True) should work  if you ever need to drop them this way